# What is the significance of forward declaration in C programming?

Tags: c, forward-declaration

I am now learning C programming through Learn C the Hard Way by Zed A. Shaw. There is this code (taking from his website):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// forward declarations
int can_print_it(char ch);
void print_letters(char arg[]);

void print_arguments(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        print_letters(argv[i]);
    }
}

void print_letters(char arg[])
{
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; arg[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        char ch = arg[i];

        if(can_print_it(ch)) {
            printf("'%c' == %d ", ch, ch);
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
}

int can_print_it(char ch)
{
    return isalpha(ch) || isblank(ch);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    print_arguments(argc, argv);
    return 0;
}
```

Don't we just can code it like this (put the `can_print_it` and `print_letters` functions at the top and remove the need for forward declaration):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int can_print_it(char ch)
{
    return isalpha(ch) || isblank(ch);
}

void print_letters(char arg[])
{
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; arg[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        char ch = arg[i];

        if(can_print_it(ch)) {
            printf("'%c' == %d ", ch, ch);
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Is there really times when the forward declaration is important and unavoidable?

Comment: "Is there really times when the forward declaration is important and unavoidable?" - yes, all the time, I don't mean you have to forward declare all the time, but it is very common and unavoidable, basically every time you have a "circular relation" between two objects, often it is needed even when they are declared in the same source

Comment: What if `func1` calls `func2`, and `func2` calls `func1`? (But the main point is header files & libraries.)

Comment: how does your approach bypass this? instead of using "short method signature" declarations, you declare&define the whole function there.

Comment: Imagine you have a larger project. Putting all the code in a single `.c` file would be an absolute nightmare, so what you typically do is split it into multiple source files. So now, to call `myFunc` defined in `a.c` from within `b.c` you need a forward declaration (usually in a header file).

Comment: Wow, really a lot of inputs. Since I am a beginner, I can't really understand all of the arguments here but I do see how this can be useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Forward declarations of functions in C typically have two different uses.

### Modules

The header of exported functions are declared in a header file which is included in a client module.

### Mutual Recursion

In mutual recursion two functions call each other repeatedly. Without a forward declaration one of the two functions will be undeclared in the body of the other.

Example:

```
int Odd(int n);

int Even(int n)
{
    return (n == 0)? 1: Odd(n - 1);
}

int Odd(int n)
{
    return (n == 0)? 0: Even(n - 1);
}
```

With a function pointer though, we can do without a forward declaration:

```
int (*odd)(int n);

int Even(int n)
{
    return (n == 0)? 1: odd(n - 1);
}

int Odd(int n)
{
    return (n == 0)? 0: Even(n - 1);
}

void Init(void)
{
    odd = Odd;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Forward declarations of functions are unavoidable whenever your call graph is cyclic; that is, whenever you have (direct or indirect) recursion between functions.

They are *useful*  if you want to separate your program into more than one translation unit, as they allow separation of declaration and definition of functions (placing the declaration in a `.h` header and the definition in a `.c` file).

Comment: I understand that computers with 1024 bytes of memory benefitted from forward declarations as they could compile C with a single pass, but why, oh why, do I have to predeclare functions in the same source file today when I have gigabytes of memory to spare?!

Comment: @Gunchars that's a good point; C++ manages to parse inline member functions that may refer to each other within their function bodies. At this point it is simply historical inertia; no one implementation can make the change without being accused of gratuitous incompatibility, and the Standard committee are understandably wary of making sweeping changes. Perhaps it may still happen; after all we are now allowed to declare variables below the start of a function.

Answer (score 3):

You should declare functions in the order that makes sense. This should be described in the coding style document you follow. One example of common design is:

- h-file with all publically available function declarations.
- c-file with all private function declarations at the top.
- then in the same c-file follows the function definition of the public functions.
- and then at the end of that c-file, the function definition of the private functions.

In addition to style and design concerns, ancient versions of C would start to "make up" function parameters and return types if there was no prototype at all visible before the function call.

Answer (score 2):

Forward declaration is upto the program's need. Programmer can design it in their own.

> Understand the significance: In C and C++, the line above represents a
>   forward declaration of a function and is the function's prototype.
>   After processing this declaration, the compiler would allow the
>   program code to refer to the entity printThisInteger in the rest of
>   the program. The definition for a function must be provided somewhere
>   (same file or other, where it would be the responsibility of the
>   linker to correctly match references to a particular function in one
>   or several object files with the definition, which must be unique, in
>   another):

Comment: If you are going to copy and paste a paragraph from Wikipedia you could at least provide a link to the [Forward declaration article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) you plagiarized.