# How do i call a function below my function

Tags: c

```
void viewMenu(){

//code

viewSellMenu();

}

void viewSellMenu(){

//code

viewMenu();

}
```

How do i have to code those 2 function so they can have a mutual relation?

Comment: Add a prototype or declaration above the function that calls it. `void viewSellMenu();`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35084608/what-is-the-significance-of-forward-declaration-in-c-programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call a function, the compiler needs to know its *declaration*, i.e. what's it called, that it's a function, and what the parameters and return type are:

```
void viewSellMenu(void); // declaration of viewSelMenu

// *definition* of viewMenu also serves as declaration
void viewMenu(){

//code

viewSellMenu();  // can be called because compiler knows declaration

}

// *definition* of viewSelMenu
void viewSellMenu(){

//code

viewMenu();

}
```

Comment: I strongly recommend adding a prototype to your declaration, i.e. `void viewSellMenu(void);`.

Comment: wait... that makes a difference in C, right?

Answer (score 0):

To use an identifier, it must be "visible" to the compiler. In C, visibility is from top to bottom. So, you have to add a declaration to a function above the function that calls it:

```
void viewSellMenu();

// rest of code
```

Since you call the function `viewSellMenu()` with no arguments, consider changing it's signature to:

```
void viewSellMenu(void);
```

and when you define it, write:

```
void viewSellMenu(void)
{
    viewMenu();
}
```

Same goes for `viewMenu()`.

Note: If a function definition exists above a function that calls it, then you don't have to add a declaration.

Comment: I strongly recommend adding a prototype to your declaration, i.e. `void viewSellMenu(void);`.

Comment: @melpomene I don't get it. `viewSellMenu` does not take `void`...

Comment: `viewSellMenu` takes no arguments. The syntax for that is `(void)`. If you just use `()`, it means "this function takes an unspecified number of arguments".

Comment: @melpomene but why should I write something that differs from what the OP is showing?

Comment: Because answers are supposed to improve/fix the code in the question. Also because OP's code only contains function definitions, not declarations, so the prototype issue doesn't really come up.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "wrong". The language allows it (for compatibility with pre-standard code from the 1980s), but it wouldn't pass code review today.

Comment: @melpomene Now I see it. The OP calls viewSellMenu with no arguments so it should rather be `void viewSellMenu(void)` like you said.